# Electrical circuit for detecting and charging a battery at 12 v

Tags: switches

I have an input source of 12 v at 6 amp. How can I use a toggle switch or a circuit that can detect if the source is active, it should let the voltage pass if present otherwise not. Also what is the best way to detect and switch on a led in case the battery that is operating has an output less than 12 v.

Answer (score 2):

The LTspice circuit file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/294c0ap0nvd8zq9/PMOS%20switch.asc) if you want to modify the circuit, and the component values on the schematic assume a 12V battery source and a circuit which disconnects the battery from the load when the battery voltage falls to about 10 V, and turns on the LED when the battery voltage falls below about 11.4 V.

[image]

Comment: @user3266789: Or did you want a charger?

Comment: I have 2 circuit requirements one is to have a kind of switch which automatically connects the battery circuit in case charging 12 v is disconnected. Other is detect the voltage in battery to be at certain level to indicated that it requires charging.